# How to navigate to SObject custom tab?

Tags: lightningnavigation

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
                    urlEvent.setParams({
                        "recordId": component.get("v.recordId"),
                        "slideDevName": "detail"
                    });
                    urlEvent.fire();
```

This piece of code can be used to navigate to details tab, related tab or chatter. How can i navigate to a custom tab ?

Comment: navigating to a custom tab within that object's record page is still not supported.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct

1. If it is a custom Objects detail page, redirect id will automatically take care of which details page irrespective of custom/standard object it is

   redirectHere : function (component, event, helper) {
   var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
   navEvt.setParams({
   "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX",
   "slideDevName": "related"
   });
   navEvt.fire();
   }
2. If it is a custom TAB (not related to any object) its just a page

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation

```
navigate : function(component, event, helper) {

    //Find the text value of the component with aura:id set to "address"
    var address = component.find("address").get("v.value");

    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

Comment: Suppose I have a page with 3 tabs in it, 1 is detail, 2nd is Related and 3rd tab is a custom component. On click of a  button I need to refresh the page and redirect to the 3rd tab in my app builder page. If I give navigate to Component, it opens the component separately in a tab. However i want to stay in the same page with my custom tab highlighted. is this possible?

Comment: No it is not possible.